# Error install in ionic cordova process

Tags: ionic-framework, windows-nt, enoent

[image]

How to solve error installation problem in ionic

Comment: try to reinstall by clearing current installed files

Comment: i did already what u say

Comment: Please do not provide code, logs, output, error messages... in images:  it is usually barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, visually impaired people cannot use their voice synthetsizer, people trying to help you cannot copy/paste the content if needed, it uses (in best cases...) 1000 times more data volume (e.g. disk space to store, data transfers....) than the equivalent text in code/citation block... and above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Installing ionic when your running behind a proxy**

Uninstall Node.js if your facing a lot of errors.(optional)

> **Install Nodejs(mandatory)**
>
> **Install Python(mandatory)**
>
> **During installation ensure that environmental variable for python is checked**

**Step 1:** 
start->cmd->(right click ) run as administrator

**Step 2:** 
type the following command **cd\** to work as a root user

**Step 3:** 
Setting up windows proxy as below(use your organisation proxies)

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.organisation.com:8000
set https_proxy=https://proxy.organisation.com:8000
```

**Step 4:**
Setting up npm proxy as below(use your organisation proxies)

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.organisation.com:8000
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.organisation.com:8000
```

**Step 5:**
**Dont navigate to the user folder(From the root folder) execute the following command**

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

which will install both ionic and cordova.

**Possible Errors:**

- Python not found.
- Windows_NT -> reason is your not an administrator.
- ECONNREFUSED -> your connection is not going through proxy check for your proxy in npm using 
  `npm config list` command.

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure Ionic to use proxy to start a project. Define below environment varible on Windows:

Varible name: PROXY (capitalized)
Varible value: http://host:port